# Tween Bounce Derivation process

Tags: javascript, tween

This is the source code of Tween.Bounce.easeOut,
I don't understand the constant 2.75, 7.5625, 0.75 and others...
What is the derivation process？

```
  if (k < (1 / 2.75)) {
    return 7.5625 * k * k;
  } else if (k < (2 / 2.75)) {
    return 7.5625 * (k -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * k + 0.75;
  } else if (k < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
    return 7.5625 * (k -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * k + 0.9375;
  } else {
    return 7.5625 * (k -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * k + 0.984375;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Robert Penner [Index](http://robertpenner.com/easing/).You can find the answer.